# how filters work in ec2.describe_instances()

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

Here is a small piece of python code which I am trying to understand
It connects to amazon ec2 instances and prints the values.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
filters =[{'Name':'tag:Name','Values':['instance_one','instance_two']}]
reservations=ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
print (reservations)
print ('#####\n')
reservations=ec2.describe_instances()
print (reservations)
```

The output is

```
{'Reservations': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '037a7801-700e-4ada-8044-b65f0126bbdb', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'date': 'Sun, 19 Aug 2018 08:56:01 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
#####

{'Reservations': [{'Groups': [], 'Instances': [{'AmiLaunchIndex': 0, 'ImageId': 'ami-d783a9b8', 'InstanceId': 'i-03e7f6391a0f523ee', 'InstanceType': 't2.micro', 'KeyName': 'datastructutre key', 'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 2, 17, 8, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Monitoring': {'State': 'disabled'}, 'Placement': {'AvailabilityZone': 'ap-south-1a', 'GroupName': '', 'Tenancy': 'default'}, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-20-16.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.20.16', 'ProductCodes': [], 'PublicDnsName': '', 'State': {'Code': 80, 'Name': 'stopped'}, 'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated (2018-08-19 02:34:57 GMT)', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-d3fdbabb', 'VpcId': 'vpc-08356c60', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'BlockDeviceMappings': [{'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 4, 28, 52, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'Status': 'attached', 'VolumeId': 'vol-09716d3308f44c63f'}}], 'ClientToken': '', 'EbsOptimized': False, 'EnaSupport': True, 'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'NetworkInterfaces': [{'Attachment': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 4, 28, 52, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-08d060230b617ca70', 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'DeviceIndex': 0, 'Status': 'attached'}, 'Description': '', 'Groups': [{'GroupName': 'launch-wizard-1', 'GroupId': 'sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58'}], 'Ipv6Addresses': [], 'MacAddress': '02:5a:17:52:69:a6', 'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-0146aab6d9503bf47', 'OwnerId': '1xxxxxxxxx', 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-20-16.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.20.16', 'PrivateIpAddresses': [{'Primary': True, 'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-172-31-20-16.ap-south-1.compute.internal', 'PrivateIpAddress': '172.31.20.16'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'Status': 'in-use', 'SubnetId': 'subnet-d3fdbabb', 'VpcId': 'vpc-08356c60'}], 'RootDeviceName': '/dev/xvda', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'SecurityGroups': [{'GroupName': 'launch-wizard-1', 'GroupId': 'sg-0e81c2a33e1039f58'}], 'SourceDestCheck': True, 'StateReason': {'Code': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown', 'Message': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown'}, 'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', 'CpuOptions': {'CoreCount': 1, 'ThreadsPerCore': 1}}], 'OwnerId': '12xxxxxxxxxx', 'ReservationId': 'r-057axxxxxxxxxxx'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '2ee752bf-4f25-4c9e-8da2-553f7ae72d96', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'date': 'Sun, 19 Aug 2018 08:56:01 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

I am not able to understand working of

```
reservations=ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
```

I have put print statements after using filter and without using filter.In using filter the first print statement prints a blank Reservations[] list while the second print statement ResponseMetadata tag followed by value comes after a long list of Reservations has printed. 
What does Filters=filters do in `reservations=ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filters)` statement?
Why is it used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines:

```
filters =[{'Name':'tag:Name','Values':['instance_one','instance_two']}]
reservations=ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
```

are saying: *"Only return instances where the Tag called `Name` has a value of either `instance_one` or `instance_two`"*

Comment: ok then inside `{Name:'tag:Name'` what does first Name says if you can point me to some tutorial where I can read it more or some more examples that would be great.Here the things are inside a list [ ] which is having a dictionary inside I am not able to understand why is it done. I am using free version of amazon services how many servers can I create to test the codes and filters I have just 1 now.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation of Boto3's -> EC2.Client.describe_instances 
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

**Filter** argument will provides you the only requested details of instance placed in that list of **Filter** argument.

Per that documentation,

> Name (string) --
>   The name of the filter. Filter names are case-sensitive.
>
> Values (list) --
>   One or more filter values. Filter values are case-sensitive.

And

> tag :key =*value* - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource. Specify the key of the tag in the filter name and the value of the tag in the filter value. For example, for the tag Purpose=X, specify tag:Purpose for the filter name and X for the filter value.

If no arguments were passed to describe_instances. All the parameters of instances will be printed.

Comment: I read the doc, what I am not clear with is suppose I want to know instance-id,association.public-dns-name then how will I use it in the code where I have used filter.How will print(response) give  me instance id or public-dns-name of the instance.I need an example or more examples to understandd how ec2.describe_instances() are working.With filters.